# Tabulator toggle all nested tables

Tags: javascript, nested, tabulator

Hi I want to use nested tables in Tabulator as per the example in the docs

[https://jsfiddle.net/2Lnyrqg4/]

```js
var nestedData = [
    {id:1, make:"Ford", model:"focus", reg:"P232 NJP", color:"white", serviceHistory:[
        {date:"01/02/2016", engineer:"Steve Boberson", actions:"Changed oli filter"},
        {date:"07/02/2017", engineer:"Martin Stevenson", actions:"Break light broken"},
    ]},
    {id:1, make:"BMW", model:"m3", reg:"W342 SEF", color:"red", serviceHistory:[
        {date:"22/05/2017", engineer:"Jimmy Brown", actions:"Aligned wheels"},
        {date:"11/02/2018", engineer:"Lotty Ferberson", actions:"Changed Oil"},
        {date:"04/04/2018", engineer:"Franco Martinez", actions:"Fixed Tracking"},
    ]},
];

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "311px",
    layout: "fitColumns",
    resizableColumns: false,
    data: nestedData,
    columns: [
        {title: "Make", field: "make"},
        {title: "Model", field: "model"},
        {title: "Registration", field: "reg"},
        {title: "Color", field: "color"},
    ],
    rowFormatter: function(row) {
        //create and style holder elements
        var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
        var tableEl = document.createElement("div");

        holderEl.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
        holderEl.style.padding = "10px 30px 10px 10px";
        holderEl.style.borderTop = "1px solid #333";
        holderEl.style.borderBotom = "1px solid #333";
        holderEl.style.background = "#ddd";

        tableEl.style.border = "1px solid #333";

        holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

        row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);

        var subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
            layout: "fitColumns",
            data: row.getData().serviceHistory,
            columns: [
                {title: "Date", field: "date", sorter: "date"},
                {title: "Engineer", field: "engineer"},
                {title: "Action", field: "actions"},
            ]
        });
    },
});
```

What I want to do is to be able to hide and show all nested tables with one click, I have found some examples on stack overflow to toggle individual rows but I want to be able to hide all of them but I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0):

To do that i suggest that you add a property to the row data of "tableOpen", that you change the state off whenever the nested table is revealed.

You would need to decide how to toggle this property, either on row click or on click of an element added by the row formatter.

Then in the rowFormatter you would check to see if ***tableOpen*** was `true` before appending the table.

```js
rowFormatter: function(row) {
    //setup nested table

    //append table if needed
    if(row.getData().tableOpen){
        row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);
    }
}
```

To toggle all the tables you could then use the ***getRows*** function to get an array of all the tables [Row Components](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/components#component-row) and then call the ***update*** function on each row to set the property of the column and then trigger a ***reformat*** which will then add or remove the nested table.

```js
var rows = table.getRows();

rows.forEach(function(row){
    row.update({tableOpen:true});
    row.reformat();
});
```